# How to successfully fill the datagridview - getting error invalid attempt to call read when reader is closed in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0

I need a quick help. I am getting an error invalid attempt to call read when reader is closed when trying to add my databagridview from the reader.

the databases is a class that calls the database connection string. and the databaseColumn is a class that has all columns names.

error for column Time_Completed
[image]

what is the issues please help

Here is the code:

```
//datagridview, bindingsource, data_apapter global objects variables
        private DataGridView dataGridView = new DataGridView();
        private BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
        private SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();


        //class objects
        Databases lemars = new Databases();
        Databases schuyler = new Databases();
        Databases detroitlakeskc = new Databases();


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void comboBox_Database_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox_Database.SelectedItem.ToString() == "LeMars21St")
            {
                GetDataToDataGridView();
            }
        }

        private void GetDataToDataGridView()
        {
            //prgBar_DataGridViewLoading
            DatabaseColumns Obj = new DatabaseColumns();
            String SqlcmdString = "Select * from dbo.AllInvoicesInReadyStatus";
            SqlDataReader reader;
            int i = 1;
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(lemars._LeMarsConnectionString))
                {

                    reader = null;
                    SqlCommand Sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(SqlcmdString, conn);
                    conn.Open();
                    reader = Sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();

                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {

                                Obj.Invoice = reader["invoice"].ToString();
                                Obj.Shipment = reader["shipment"].ToString();
                                Obj.Project = reader["Project"].ToString();
                                Obj.InvoiceDateTB = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["invoiceDateTB"]);
                                Obj.CreatedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["CreatedDate"]);
                                Obj.TypeName = reader["typeName"].ToString();
                                Obj.ExportedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["exportedDate"]);
                                Obj.StatusName = reader["statusName"].ToString();
                                Obj.Total = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["total"]);
                                Obj.ImportStatus = reader["import_status"].ToString();
                                //DateTime dateFacturation;
                                int colIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("Time_Completed");
                                if (!reader.IsDBNull(colIndex))
                                    Obj.TimeCompleted = reader.GetDateTime(colIndex);
                                Obj.ErrorDescription = reader["ERROR_DESCRIPTION"].ToString();

                                //bindingSource.DataSource = reader;
                                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                                dt.Load(reader);
                                dataGridView.DataSource = dt;

                                i++;
                            }
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            reader.Close();
                        }
                          conn.Close();
                    }                  
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: I am getting the following error, so the datagridview never loads all the 12 columns I am trying to add.  ERROR:   invalid attempt to call read when reader is closed

Comment: Guessing dt.load is closing the reader after it's finished.

Comment: But why and how to resolve it?

Comment: Either use a while read look or the dt.load method. Not both on the same reader.

Comment: Can you add a sample of code on that solution you are providing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataTable.Load` method automatically closes currently running `DataReader` instance, hence it will fail at the next iteration (the exception clearly said that the `DataReader` is already closed).

To fix this issue, call `DataTable.Load` immediately after `ExecuteReader` (i.e. after checking by `HasRows`) and you can iterate `DataTable` contents from that, as given in example below:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(lemars._LeMarsConnectionString))
{
     reader = null;
     SqlCommand Sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(SqlcmdString, conn);
     conn.Open();
     reader = Sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
     if (reader.HasRows)
     {
         try
         {
             DataTable dt = new DataTable();
             dt.Load(reader);

             for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
             {
                 Obj.Invoice = dt.Rows[i]["invoice"].ToString();
                 Obj.Shipment = dt.Rows[i]["shipment"].ToString();
                 Obj.Project = dt.Rows[i]["Project"].ToString();

                 // other stuff
             }

             dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
         }
         finally
         {
             conn.Close();
         }
     }
}
```

**Update 1**:

Since one of your datetime column may contain `DBNull.Value`, you can check using either `Convert.IsDBNull`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dt.Rows[i]["Time_Completed"]))
    {
        Obj.TimeCompleted = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["Time_Completed"]);
    }
}
```

Or with `is` operator with `DBNull`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (!(dt.Rows[i]["Time_Completed"] is DBNull))
    {
        Obj.TimeCompleted = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["Time_Completed"]);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use ternary operator and set `DateTime.MinValue` if the column has null value.

Related issues:

[Error: Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed after the while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873618/error-invalid-attempt-to-call-read-when-reader-is-closed-after-the-while-loop)

[C# - Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253579/c-sharp-invalid-attempt-to-call-read-when-reader-is-closed)

Comment: thanks man, that worked. Now I was able to add the data to my DataGridView. but there is 1 issue, one of the columns Time_Completed is  a date column and most of the time is always going to be NULL, so for some reason I am getting an error. I will add the error above my first post.

Comment: @AndresBryan29 Answer updated with example usage of `DBNull` checking to `Time_Completed` column.

Comment: Amazing bro, that worked nicely and beautifully, thanks for all your help. I learned a lot working on this.

Comment: @AndresBryan29 You can accept an answer that solved your problem by clicking the "accept" mark beside the answer, indicating that you've found a best solution. It's not an obligation to do so.